# Custom link with JS which opens in a new tab (for package configuration)

Tags: javascript, managed-package, custom-link

For the package configuration, I need a Salesforce 'custom link'.
The 'custom link' has to open in a new window.
I need JavaScript for it. 
I tried it with following code but it does not work:

```
window.open("http://google.de");
```

Is there a way I can get this working (with JavaScript)? 
Thanks
Edit: I tried it in a VF-Page, but it should also work in lightning.
Edit2: I have a strong feeling that it is not possible to use JS for a package configuration link (I tried the 'custom link' on the home tab and it was working there).

Comment: Is it a VF page or Lightning?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it strongly seems that it is not possible to use 'OnClick JavaScript' for a package configuration link:
A possible solution would be to use a 'Visual Force' page (for 'Custom Link').
 Inside this 'Visual Force' page, there could be either a JS script with a redirect to the external page or an HTML link to the external page.

Answer (score 1):

Is it okay to achieve this without JS?

When you create a custom link you can select always open in New Window/tab it will always open in new window irrespective of your environment(Classic/Lightning)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I really need JS for that. Because I want to try a workaround for: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ezaQQAQ